# Adding the "button down" effect on keydown with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, button, keydown

How can I add the "button down" effect when a button is selected and a key is pressed?  The behaviour of the actual press works, it's just no effect is ever shown.

To be more specific:
I have a set of buttons that can be traversed through using the left and right arrow keys.  And when Enter is pressed, the currently selected button will carry-out it's onclick behaviour.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/DBLem/

```
var index = 0;
var buttons = $('button');
var max = buttons.length - 1;
var buttonOn = buttons.eq(index).addClass('on');

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 39:
        {
            index++;
            if (index > max) {
                index = 0;
            }
            break;
        }
    case 37:
        {
            index--;
            if (index < 0) {
                index = max;
            }
            break;
        }
    case 13:
        {
            buttonOn.trigger('click');
        }
    }
    buttonOn = buttons.eq(index);
    buttons.removeClass('on');
    buttonOn.addClass('on');
});


$('button').click(function(){
    alert(this.innerHTML);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i'd save an id of the element which currently has focus like this and then click it when the user presses enter:

```
var id; 

$("button").focus(function () {
     id = this.id;
});

$(window).keydown(function(e){
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code === 13){
        $('#'+id).click();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("button").click(function(){

      $(this).animate({ marginLeft: "2px", marginTop: "2px" }, 100, function(){ 
         $(this).css({marginLeft:"0px", marginTop:"0px"});
         //On click logic goes here
      });

    }).keyup(function(e){

      if(e.which == 13){
        $(this).trigger('click');
      }
    });
```